# csv file to Pandas Series(time object)

Tags: python, pandas

firstly,i have a 0404.csv like this

```
"time","xxxxx","xxxxxxx"

"09:00:00","xxxx","xxxxxx"

"09:00:01","xxxxx","xxxxx"

"09:00:02","xxxxxx","xxxxxx"
..........
```

i want to get the series of datetime like datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 9, 0, 1) datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 9, 0, 2).......

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv("0404.csv", usecols = ['time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your time column only includes **time**, you can't extract the **date** from it.

```
       time
0  09:00:00
1  09:00:01
2  09:00:02
```

So you need to make it yourself, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("0404.csv", usecols = ['time'])

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-04-04 {}'.format(x), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

the output will be like this:

```
                 time
0 2019-04-04 09:00:00
1 2019-04-04 09:00:01
2 2019-04-04 09:00:02
```